# Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xc3 0xbf

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to decode jpeg file using tf.image.decode_jpeg but it says its not a JPEG file. I don't know what the problem is.Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

This is my test code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

path = "/root/PycharmProjects/mscoco/train2014/COCO_train2014_000000291797.jpg"

with open(path, "r", encoding="latin-1") as f:
    image = f.read()


encoded_jpeg = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
decoded_jpeg = tf.image.decode_jpeg(encoded_jpeg, channels=3)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

sess.run(decoded_jpeg, feed_dict={encoded_jpeg: image})
```

And This is the error:

```
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xc3 0xbf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 947, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py", line 450, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid JPEG data, size 165886
     [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_Placeholder_0)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/mytf/models/im2txt/im2txt/data/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    sess.run(decoded_jpeg, feed_dict={encoded_jpeg: image})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 710, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 908, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 958, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 978, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid JPEG data, size 165886
     [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_Placeholder_0)]]
Caused by op 'DecodeJpeg', defined at:
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/mytf/models/im2txt/im2txt/data/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    decoded_jpeg = tf.image.decode_jpeg(encoded_jpeg, channels=3)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_image_ops.py", line 283, in decode_jpeg
    name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2317, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I cannot

Comment: any reason you are using tensorflow and not PIL/pillow which is more of pythons default library for imaging?

Answer (score 3):

You're reading an image file as if it were a text file.

Just change the line:

```
with open(path, "r", encoding="latin-1") as f:
```

with

```
with open(path, "rb") as f:
```

To read the image as a binary ("rb" = Read Binary) file.

Comment: Well spotted. It turns out that `c3 bf` is the UTF-8 encoding of `ff` in latin-1, which is the first byte of JFIF's start of image marker (being binary data, it is incorrect to parse it as either encoding).